# Overlaying of two image with text on below

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to implement an image that has an image overlayed on it. Since I need to tell that this image has a video content on it. Now from some post here I've encountered this code (pardon me I lost the link) which actually works but problem is it also overlay the text content below the images. For reference of what exactly I'm trying to achieve I have this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/266/). I just hardcoded on what I wanted to see and here's the code anyways:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="imageOne image"></div>
<div class="imageTwo image"></div>
</div>

<div><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Text should be below the image</div>
```

I just need to fix the part where images overlaps on my text as well. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not seeing images over the text, or is that what you are trying to achieve? (over as in on top of not above)

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/272/) what you want?

Comment: @SamyS.Rathore Almost but not exactly since you already set a width and height on your code wherein in my end I won't be sure about the size of the image until I set it.

Comment: @atmd that is what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed version in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/270/

Just a few tweaks needed. Specifically using

```
position:relative
```

on .container and .imageOne

and

```
top:0
```

on .image

Comment: Almost but not. See if I have removed the breaks it still covers up the text http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/270/

Comment: Just a question: why do you set the position twice on imageOne? since you use two CSS class as far as I know. sorry but I also need to convert this into a inline so I need to clear things out and I'm no expert on this field.

Comment: imageOne needs to be position:relative and imageTwo needs to be position:absolute. You can do that anyway you want, but I just modified your code as simply as possible. Make sense?

Comment: Also, if you specify width/height on the container (not the images) you can remove position:relative on imageOne

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thanks @Alex as well for the help. :D

Comment: Correct @Alex :-) Guess it depends on if he wants to specify width/height on the image or container. I used image since that was  already in his code.

Comment: @JoeHakooz I was going to arrive at something similar to your solution, but have always been told its bad practice to leave container dimensions undefined :)

Comment: I agree @Alex. I would prefer to change the container instead of the first child element.

Answer (score 1):

Currently your divs overlap because you have the parent container set to a fixed position, therefore it will be anchored to (0,0) of its parent, any other elements are then drawn to the default (0,0) coords of there parent (body in this case).

In order to fix this, make the `.container` elements position `relative`, the text div will now have its position drawn at `(0,100)` as `container` has a height of 100px relative to the body.

This also makes sense for the case that you want your `.image` to overlap in `.container`, both `.image` divs have their position set to `absolute` meaning they will be drawn at (0,0) within their parent (`.container` in this case).

Updated css would look like this:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Please note that the parent div now contains information of the width and height, the children images now inherit this information from the parent, however you could make them smaller. Hope this helps :)

[JSFiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/uS7nw/300/)

Comment: Did that fix it for you? Added a JSFiddle link.